# Domain Models in dynamic languages?

Tags: dynamic-typing, hexagonal-architecture

I create Hexagonal Architecture based software with TypeScript or C#. The heart of Hexagonal Architecture is the Domain Model.

For example, for a user of application `y`, the domain model might look like this:

```typescript
// typescript

export interface UserEntity {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  email: string;
  someFunction(arg: string): something
}
```

This interface will be the driving force for all user `use-cases`, `ports` and `adaptors`.

How would I model domain objects in a dynamic language like JavaScript?

Comment: just program as normal and pretend you have type enforcement

Comment: I guess the mental block is coming from thinking that the "model" is your data structures. E.g. you said "the domain model might look like this" - that's not the domain model, that's just a somewhat anemic data structure that's a part of the domain model. The domain model is not data entities - it's that + all the behavior around that data that directly captures the domain logic. The model is how you (and your team) conceptualized and approached the problem, a distillation of what you understood from learning about the domain (as opposed to how someone else might have done it).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović while that is true, my example was modelling a user with a "sign up new user" use case. Where a signup is not part of the domain model, but is part of the application use case. The `someFunction` puts forward the idea that there is more to the model than the data.

This is simply an example. The point was about dynamic vs static. Not what a domain model is.

Comment: My comment was more of a side note. What I was trying to say is that you shouldn't hyper-fixate on the wrong thing - meaning, on trying to reproduce the exact form of the code in a different language. E.g. in JavaScript you may end up not having any interfaces explicitly appear in code (they may exist only in your documentation), yet it'll still be the same domain model. You might use a different set of tools to model the same overall thing. You could encode the required structure in factory functions or constructors. In a different approach, you could involve some object validation scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let a type system interfere with building the concept of a "domain model." There is no special way to do this in dynamic languages. Focus on the core concept of a domain model — business logic. Organize and group these business functions into modules. Object-oriented languages might call these "classes" or... well... "objects" in the case of JavaScript, because everything is an object in JavaScript. Even classes.

You need to clearly define what the business rules are to begin with. Only then can you organize them into cohesive modules. Use whatever structures the dynamic language has available. Just make sure your "domain model":

- Enforces rules that must be true regardless of the user interface.
- Does not depend on types defined in other layers of the architecture.

  - But may depend on the base level types and data structures inherent to the language.

Otherwise, just write code.